# How to split data array in Angular Service?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have data form as below

```
{
  "COLUMNS": ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5"],

  "DATA": [
             [Test, Test, Test, Test, Test],
             [Test, Test, Test, Test, Test]
          ]
}
```

I want to split this data two pieces in my service and i want to get my columns and data seperate.

I try to use `.shift()` method as below but it's return undefined.

My service:

```
getService(): any{
 this.http.get<string[]>(this.url2).pipe(map(data => {
  return data.shift()
}))
```

}

My component:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.columns = this.productService.getProductsService();
  }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem . Here my solution

```
public general : any[];
public columns : string[];
public gridData: Test[];

this.productService.getProductsService().subscribe((res: Test[]) => {
  this.general = res;
  this.columns = Object.values(this.general).shift();
  this.gridData = Object.values(this.general)[1];
  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning an Observable in the `getService()`, you should subscribe to it to get the result first and then do whatever you want

**Example**:

```js
this.productService.getProductsService().subscribe(c => {
  this.columns = c;
});
```

Also, you should correct the name of the method that you are trying to call from the service : `getProductsService()` or `getService()`

Comment: I'm returning any.. as you see my return is 'return data.shift()' this is returns Array<string>.

Comment: No, it will return Observable<string[]> and not Array<string>.

Comment: Ok, I'm subscribing now but when i subscribe data i'm getting error for 'c.shift()' because i want to split my array data as columns and data

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not use the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook to load data.

Secondly, according to your types you expect an array of strings `string[]`, but say that you want to split another data structure if I understood your inquiry correctly. `array.shift()` removes the first element from the array and returns it. When you shift `string[]` you get a `string` but you say that the intention is to split an object.

```
{
  "COLUMNS": ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5"],

  "DATA": [
             [Test, Test, Test, Test, Test],
             [Test, Test, Test, Test, Test]
          ]
}
```

^ this one will be something like `{ COLUMNS: string[], DATA: Test[][] }`

Thirdly, what is the `Test` type?

```
...
[
  [Test, Test, Test, Test, Test],
  [Test, Test, Test, Test, Test]
]
...
```

Fourthly, you should not use `any`.

Finally, my suggestion is to fix types first. Then use SOLID. The http-service should only request data and return it as is. That's it, no mutations, no side effects. Splitting the received data is not the http-service responsibility obviously.

Comment: as you said columns are string[] but data array is Test[] and think about any[] because Test1 can be string Test2 can be number... What i need just split columns and data and then use them separately